# How to set up a proxy on Android for all the applications?

Tags: android, proxy

As you know, only the browsers will use the proxy set up in the WiFi settings of your Android smartphone. So that means the other apps will ignore my proxy and use my real IP.

After some research, I heard about the Drony app. But it is not available for my version of Android. It says :

*"This app isn't available for your device because it was made for an older version of Android"*

I don't want to root my smartphone in order to use another app that could fix my issue.

Do you know any solution to force the Apps to use my proxy settings without rooting my device?

Comment: What you write is not correct. A lot of apps use the proxy settings but if you perform HTTPS-interception most apps will stop working because they don't trust the proxy certificate. And in recent versions of Chrome also the web browser will no longer work because the proxy certificate is not issued by a CA that is part of the Certificate Transparency initiative. The only apps Of course there a few apps that totally ignore proxy settings, this is usually caused the the used development framework like Xamarin (which AFAIK does not support proxy at all).